# Porting graphics drawing from android to standard java

Tags: java, java-2d

I have an android application which draws images directly onto the canvas.
It uses notably paths and beziers.

I now need to port this to a windows app written in standard java and am having difficulty in finding the correct graphics library to use.

I need to create bitmaps in memory, drawn with a path.
The path needs to be able to hold lines, beziers, ovals and hollow rectangles.
The resulting image is then blitted into the output graphic a number of times.

I have looked at Graphics2D, but the path drawing does not permit creating ovals as a part of it.

Is there a workaround or another standard library available ?
Is there an android canvas equivalent within java ?

Comment: You could have a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths in Java2D (in the form of `java.awt.geom.Path2D` or `java.awt.geom.GeneralPath`) can have any `java.awt.Shape` appended to them. `java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D` represents a circle or oval, and it implements `java.awt.Shape` so you can add one to a Path2D.

You can draw paths onto a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` and draw the buffered image onto the screen.

The Java2D API really is what you need.

Comment: Thank you @Erwin for confirming this for me.  I presume that GeneralPath would be the best option for me, so that I can directly call moveTo, lineTo, curveTo, etc.  Just need to see how I can convert my ellipse coordinates (4 corners of the bounding rectangle) to the Ellipse2D shape.